# I can't boot into Live CD/USB in an old computer

Tags: boot, live-usb, acer, live-cd

I've an Acer TravelMate 250. It had Windows XP preinstalled but I've changed te OS several times, Ubuntu Server 16.04, Xubuntu 18.04, etc.

To improve performance I want to install Lubuntu 18.04.2 or Puppy Linux but I can't boot into the Live CD/USB. I change the boot sencuence in the BIOS but after a while the OS installed in the Hard Drive boots. If I extract the Hard Drive before booting the message "No Operative System detected"

To make the Live CD I've used Brasero and Rufus and BalenaEtcher for the USB.

PD: The laptop has a 32 bits processor and an old BIOS, not UEFI.

Edit:
1. I can't boot into Ubuntu Server 16.04
   I can boot into Xubuntu 18.04?
2. I can't boot into Lubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
3. I've not checked with md5sum
4. I have checked that I have downloaded the 32-bit iso of Lubuntu

Comment: You write that you can't boot into the Live CD/USB with Lubuntu 18.04 LTS; 1. Can you still boot into Ubuntu Server 16.04 or Xubuntu 18.04? 2. Can you boot into Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS? 3. Have you checked with md5sum, that the download was good? 4. Did you check that you have downloaded the 32-bit iso of Lubuntu?

Comment: Did you upgrade your BIOS firmware with latest version? If not, please do it first and then you attempt to boot using  your live USB.

Comment: Considering your edit, a few considerations: There's absolutely NO reason for booting ones and not the others except the ones that don't are corrupt. Also, using Rufus for a BIOS installing you need to make sure the options MBR/BIOS are selected (but that's likely the default anyway).

Comment: Some computers are too old to boot from USB. Plop boot manager can be used to allow USB booting.- https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html. Otherwise, I have had most luck booting flash drives made using mkusb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all you comments!!!

After updating BIOS, discarting USB and using a new DVD (another DVD burned with another PC) everything worked.